# How to implement (SSL/TLS) secure communication through normal Java Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, starttls

How can I secure ordinary socket communication? I wrote a Jabber client that can only connect to dedicated SSL ports(5223) (using SSLSocket). The normal way is to connect to Jabber standard port 5222 and request `starttls`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: what have you tried? And not to sound stupid but have you checked their is an SSL Server implementation of the Server you are trying to connect to. I don't use jabber so I don't know. If there is no server running SSL to connect to then your SSL client is a waste of time!

Comment: Google have 5223 Port on talk.google.com, but most of every Servers giving us traditional starttls method. i don't know how to Secure communication after requesting to enable TLS.

Comment: creating a SSL socket in java is verify similar to creating a standard Socket. Can you provide some code along with the error message you are getting?

Comment: [here](http://pastebin.com/QRgSzhB2 ) aha, when i tried with sslsocket i couldn't even get connect to port 5222.

Comment: see Greg's comment below. On a side note, a SSL socket wont be able to communicate to a non SSL server and the other way around

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking, but you can layer a secure socket on an existing normal (non-secure) socket by using the [SSLSocketFactory.createSocket()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#createSocket%28java.net.Socket,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20boolean%29) method. This is one way to "upgrade" a socket using something like starttls. But this is doing things the hard way. Almost certainly your XMPP library will provide high-level access to this kind of functionality.

Comment: @Bijoy: are you really saying you want to implement your own SSL/TLS library (even though there is one provided for you in the JRE: JSSE)? That's a bit what your title sounds like. However, you probably wouldn't ask on SO, if it was what you really wanted to do, you'd just go through the RFCs (in this case, good luck...). If you just want to write your own XMPP library and upgrade a normal TCP socket to an SSL/TLS socket, use Gregs suggestion.

Comment: Ah, Sorry. Communication error, i exactly want to code my own XMPP Library not SSL/TLS library.

Comment: if i assign SSLSocketFactory.createSocket() to a Socket after send startls will that close current connection established to the Socket object?

Answer (score 1):

Expectation Management: I haven't tried this with Jabber.  But it works with GMail's SMTP server, so maybe...

Here's how to upgrade a socket to an SSL socket, where `socket` is the original (non-TLS) connection:

```
SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) ((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).createSocket(
                       socket, 
                       socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), 
                       socket.getPort(), 
                       true);
InputStream inputStream = sslSocket.getInputStream();
OutputStream outputStream = sslSocket.getOutputStream();
// reads from the socket
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
// writes to the socket
OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
```